# What's best way to store scraped data to curate a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am building a bunch of crawlers with `scrapy` (python) and I would like to gather this data into a webapp (calendar, example: https://lectures.london/). What this the best way to store the data?

Comment: It's difficult to tell without more informations. But in general, an sqlite database is enough for most app and project.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the crawled website to a dictionary (checkout the [BeautifulSoup parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)).
Now dump the dictionary to a json string and store the json string in a json database (e.g. MongoDB or Postgres).